# Google Play Services - No longer work properly with IL2CPP

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

I came across something funny. 
In one of my apps, I have Google Play services (IAP, Leaderboard, Achievements, latest version, 1.22).
This worked fine. I recently had to rebuild the app as 64-bit. 
Now, I notice that these services only seem to work the first time the app is loaded.
If I quit the app, and reopen it, the services no longer work. 
I found that this is related to the app being active in the background (as Android doesn't really kill the app). If I clear the app from memory (swipe up, kill task or similar), and reopen the app, the Play services work again.

Did anyone come across this as well? Any tips where to look at or fixes?

Much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
I've found that the issue occurs when moving from MONO to IL2CPP builds (which is required for the 64-bit).
I've updated Unity IAP and Google Play Games plugin to the latest versions, and set the build platform to .NET 4.x. All has been updated and builds fine, however, the issue remains. Confirmed this is due to IL2CPP.

**UPDATE2:**
When it breaks, this is the debug log from LogCat:

06-01 11:56:47.132: I/UnityIAP(12788): Calling getPurchaseHistory with continuation token: null
06-01 11:56:47.146: E/Unity(12788): InvalidOperationException: There was an error creating a GameServices object. Check for log errors from GamesNativeSDK
06-01 11:56:47.146: E/Unity(12788):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.GameServicesBuilder.Build (GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.PlatformConfiguration configRef) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
06-01 11:56:47.146: E/Unity(12788):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.InitializeGameServices () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
06-01 11:56:47.146: E/Unity(12788):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient+<>c__DisplayClass21_0.b__0 (System.Int32 result) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
06-01 11:56:47.146: E/Unity(12788):   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
06-01 11:56:47.146: E/Unity(12788):   at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaProxy.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
06-01 11:56:47.146: E/Unity(12788):   at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.InvokeJavaProxyMeth
06-01 11:56:47.355: I/UnityIAP(12788): Purchase history response: 0

-- It seems it refuses to re-initialize correctly, as when I try to purchase an item during this break, I see this in the log:

06-01 11:59:50.894: I/Unity(12788): BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.
06-01 11:59:50.894: I/Unity(12788): UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
06-01 11:59:50.894: I/Unity(12788): UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
06-01 11:59:50.894: I/Unity(12788): UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
06-01 11:59:50.894: I/Unity(12788): UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
06-01 11:59:50.894: I/Unity(12788): UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()

**UPDATE3:**
Found that this is a known issue currently being looked into by Unity:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2018-3-android-4-x-5-x-il2cpp-crash-unityiap.681982/

In the meantime, there are some workarounds here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-2018-3-13-unitypurchasing-dont-initialize-after-application-quit.665497/

---

Comment: Is this happening on a built version of your app and opened on a physical phone? Does it also happen in the Unity editor?

Comment: Hi! This happens on physical phones. I cannot test it in the editor, as you cannot simulate closing the app and keeping it in memory like on an Android. I haven't changed anything in the code, I just build a 64-bit version. That's the only difference between the working and 'non-working' version.

Comment: UPDATE: I've found that the issue occurs when moving from MONO to IL2CPP builds (which is required for the 64-bit).

Comment: Nice! Would you mind creating a solution for your question and selecting it as the answer? It's great for future people that have this issue.

Comment: Well, it's not solved yet :) Since we need to update our apps to 64 bit before August 2019, the only way to build a 64 bit app via Unity is by using IL2CPP... and the issue is still present. Just merely confirmed it is due to IL2CPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this is a known issue currently being looked into by Unity:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2018-3-android-4-x-5-x-il2cpp-crash-unityiap.681982/

In the meantime, there are some workarounds here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-2018-3-13-unitypurchasing-dont-initialize-after-application-quit.665497/